# What's the right 'T' for a Func<T> that returns itself?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

A function that returns a value:

```
public object ReturnValue() { return new object(); }
Func<object> funcReturnValue = ReturnValue;
```

A function that retuns a function that returns a value:

```
public Func<object> ReturnFunc() { return ReturnValue; }
Func<Func<object>> funcReturnFunc = ReturnFunc;
```

So far, so good. I'm having trouble with a function that returns itself:

```
public *something* ReturnSelf() { return ReturnSelf; }
Func<*something*> funcReturnSelf = ReturnSelf;
```

Clearly, `*something*` is going to be a `Func<T>` of some kind, but I'm not sure what.
At first glance I guess it's going to be infinity recursive, since `ReturnSelf`
returns a function that returns a function that returns a function...

Context: A state machine using functions for states. It works fine using
a class variable to keep the current state:

```
private Action _currentState;

private void StateOne() {
    if (IsTuesday) {
        _currentState = StateTwo;
    }
}

prvivate void StateTwo() {
    if (IsRaining) {
        _currentState = StateOne;
    }
}

private void StateEngine() {
    while (true) {
        _currentState();
        // set tuesday/raining/etc.
    }
}
```

...but that feels too much like keeping state in a global.
I'd far prefer something closer to:

```
private Func<*somthing*> StateOne() {
    if (IsTuesday) {
        return StateTwo;
    } else {
        return StateOne;
    }
}

prvivate Func<*something*> StateTwo() {
    if (IsRaining) {
        return StateOne;
    } else {
        return StateTwo;
    }
}

private void StateEngine() {
    Func<*something*> currentState = StateOne;
    while (true) {
        Func<*something*> nextState = currentState();
        // set tuesday/raining/etc.
        currentState = nextState;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Or should I just stick with the working solution?

Comment: I realize this is probably just a simplified example but I fail to see what information `StateOne` and `StateTwo` are conveying. You are only ever assigning values to `currentState` and never reading it, so what's the purpose of those methods?

Comment: I suppose the question could be asked: if you are using functions to represent states, what are the functions *of*, and in what way do they represent one state or another? Say they must return an `int`, then you only need a `Func<int>` which can access a variable containing another `Func<int>` which it can call. This is very similar to the way LINQ works

Comment: @Xerillio, `currentState` is read in `StateEngine`, it picks which of the two functions to call next.

Comment: @Charlieface, functions represent state by taking different code paths in different functions - if we're in state one we do one thing, if we're in state two, we do another. The first example ("It works fine using a class variable...") does what you suggest, keeps the current state in a variable, but the downside of that approach is that every state function has to rememeber to set the state if it has to change. Forcing functions to return state means they can't forget.

Comment: Think about the way LINQ works. Each function uses the result of the previous function (remember that extension methods are just standard methods with syntax sugar), so e.g. `list.Where(...).OrderBy(..)` means that `OrderBy` will call `Where` to get its result to sort, `Where` will call the `list` to get its result to filter, this passes back up the chain to the final result. So you can just use one function call `ToList` at the end and get the final result.

Comment: ... @J.Molenkamp's answer is roughly what I was trying to say, except instead of returning a new delegate, store each call's result in that delegate's state and just return the actual result

Comment: Intresting. That's going to need some thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `Func<T>` you could define a `delegate` which returns a value of that `delegate` type. Delegates can be used to pass function references as arguments to another function, or in this case to return a function reference from a function ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)).

Example:

```cs
class Program
{

  private delegate StateDelegate StateDelegate();

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Program program = new Program();
    StateDelegate stateHandler = program.HandleStateOne;
    
    // Execute HandleStateOne, returns HandleStateTwo
    stateHandler = stateHandler.Invoke(); 

    // Execute HandleStateTwo, returns reference to HandleStateOne    
    stateHandler = stateHandler.Invoke();
  }

  private StateDelegate HandleStateOne()
  {
    // Do something state specific...
    return HandleStateTwo;
  }

  private StateDelegate HandleStateTwo()
  {
    // Do something state specific...
    return HandleStateOne;
  }

  // Literally return reference to the function itself
  private StateDelegate ReturnSelf()
  {
    return ReturnSelf;
  }
}
```

Comment: Briliant, thanks, just what I was looking for (something like `typedef` for C).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the help of an extra type:

```
class State
{
    private Func<State> _func; 
    
    public State(Func<State> func)
    {
        _func = func;
    }
    
    public State Invoke() => _func();
}
```

And then you can write:

```
bool IsTuesday = false;
bool IsRaining = false;
State StateOne = null;
State StateTwo = null;

StateOne = new State
(
    () =>
    {
        if (IsTuesday) {
            return StateTwo;
        } else {
            return StateOne;
        }
    }
);
    
StateTwo = new State
(
    () =>
    {
        if (IsRaining) {
            return StateOne;
        } else {
            return StateTwo;
        }
    }
);
```

And, of course:

```
void StateEngine() {
    State currentState = StateOne;
    while (true) {
        var nextState = currentState.Invoke();
        // set tuesday/raining/etc.
        currentState = nextState;
    }
}
```

---

We may do a little more, with an implicit conversion to `Func<State>` (and then you don't need an `invoke` method anymore):

```
public static implicit operator Func<State> (State state)
{
    return state._func;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
void StateEngine() {
    Func<State> currentState = StateOne;
    while (true) {
        Func<State> nextState = currentState();
        // set tuesday/raining/etc.
        currentState = nextState;
    }
}
```

So, `Func<State>` returns something that can be converted implicitly into `Func<State>`.

[Code in SharpLap](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxAgrgOwD4AEBMAjALABQZwA9pQDYAEAklACrpxQAmEAnnQLx0AZhBpQ4AbgrV6TAEoQAlpiUBzfkJFjJpAMowI8OnoNwA8pjjrM6GjW3HDDuMwDulKzbtkyT85YEWLkb68GQAFGR0UXRhAJT8AHyR0QDeydHRCoIxTKzsXNzxaaQZpdG4AOzBJq6U2mVRAL50cKKWxQ2lldXwfvUNjel0g6Sx/VE+Ic5uVnBBTuFDcYlDHQ1ZOVDySqpFQ53dvhbjpc2tYnRrnVGHU7UnGSOPZGPepLgALD1wAKKYKko4MsrnRcABWAA8TgSdAAxugEAg4JgYE51EcJEMXAALBQ0SxhGAYOB7EoNcFQqYwiwAD1RU3U8MRyPpJjiD2iAHpOXQxDA6DA2JweJyEIplP9OXAYLCAHT7aJMpEotEBOB0pwnEYjMgEb5kEEABwQCgAbiZQZDoXQAPqCLCw8R0IZDXAAZm+YQp1vtmFhsVWCqidod6l9jqGT2iro9uEIADY6AowIaaApYQp+ZRDYgDJQEJbKSYYWE0bATAGyVEQRluuX4LKQ36tWRGkA===)